# Getting sqlDate from database

Tags: sql, groovy

I have in database Date: 08-08-08 08:08:08
I wanna read this value from groovy so I have select: `select * from myDatabase`

now I wanna read this:

```
def sdfDate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
println sdfDate.format(rows.MyDate)
```

where rows is groovy result set
but this return just 2008-08-08 00:00:00. Where are HH:MM:SS ?!?

thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it. I have to add property to sql conection:
`prop.put ("oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible", "true")` and then these select return what I want